# Ethernet not working after installing Security Update 2020-002 10.14.6

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, ethernet

Mac OS X showed that a new update was available on my MacBook Air (2019) which I connect to the internet with using a USB-C to ethernet connector. [ I don't use wi-fi at all for health reasons.] After installing the update, my Mac no longer recognises the ethernet connection - the connection does not show up on the switch. I purchased a new USB-C to ethernet adaptor, and it too does not work ... from which I have figured out that the problem appears to be Apple's update. I am running Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.

Any suggestions as to how to get my MacBook Air running again with ethernet ... is it possible to just install a new (or old or backup version of) the ethernet driver? If so, does anyone know which file to switch. Many thanks

Comment: Security Update 2020-003 has just been released: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2042

Answer (score 2):

As follow up to this very frustrating problem ...

1. On further analysis, the problem is that ONE of the USB-C ports stopped working (for both ethernet adaptors, and also for standalone USB to USB-C adaptors). The other USB-C port remained working fine.
2. After shifting the power input to the 'dead' port, that appears to have reset it, and it is now working again. I am suprised that this helped when re-starting the computer etc made no difference.

Comment: Another user in Italy has confirmed the same problem with the security update, and confirmed the same solution worked for him

Comment: I had the same problem - the frontmost left USB-C port was not working, plugging power directly into it reset it and it works again.